# Función que devuelva una lista con el máximo de cada lista, sin max() PYTHON

Tags: python, lista, maxima

Quería saber como escribir una función `max_de_listas(l)` que devuelva una lista con los máximos de cada lista. Sin utilizar la función Python `max()`. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> max_de_listas([[1,3,4], [23,-2,0,99], [150,-222,45,2,-1]])
[4, 99, 150]
```

Comment: Podrías agregar en tu pregunta lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora por favor? No vamos a hacer esa función por ti.

Comment: Primero tienes que hacer una función que encuentre el [máximo de una sola lista](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+find+highest+value+in+list+without+max), que llamaremos `mayor_lista`. Luego en la función `max_de_listas` solo tienes que mapear esa función a cada sublista. Para eso puedes usar una comprehensión: `return [mayor_lista(subl) for subl in l]`

Answer (score 0):

Como  no sabemos cual es tu problema, dividiremos el ejercicio en pequeños problemas independientes.

**Recorrer una lista de listas.**

Podemos recorrer una lista con `for` de dos maneras:

- Por indice.

```
for indice in range(len(lista)):
    print(lista[indice])
```

- Por los valores de la lista.

```
for numero in lista:
    print(numero)
```

En ambos casos recorremos la lista e imprimimos los valores.

Para este ejercicio utilizamos las dos formas:

```
    for lista in lista_de_listas:
        maximo = lista[0]
        for i in range(1, len(lista)):
```

**Calcular el máximo de una lista.**

Recorremos la lista por indice y vamos guardando en la variable `maximo` cada vez que encontremos un valor mayor. Se inicia `maximo` con el primer valor de la lista.

```
        maximo = lista[0]
        for i in range(1, len(lista)):
            if lista[i] > maximo:
                maximo = lista[i]
```

```
        lista_de_maximos.append(maximo)
```

Comenta si sigues teniendo problemas.

Comment: Gracias por hacerle la tarea a alguien :D

Comment: @TomyGijon perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solución basada en el comentario de @aeportugal:

```
from functools import partial, reduce

max = partial(reduce, lambda x, y: (x > y) * x + (x <= y) * y)
print([max(l) for l in listas])
```